# pygame throwing: cam.start() OSError: ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON) failure : 22, Invalid

Tags: python, pygame, camera, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to work with raspberry pi 4 and OV9281-110 camera ( https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/OV9281-110_Camera)

When I try to run pygame to read camera input I get the following error:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folderPath/test2pygame.py", line 10, in <module>
    cam.start()
OSError: ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON) failure : 22, Invalid argument
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
if camlist:
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0])
    cam.start()
    image = cam.get_image()
    print(image)
```

Could someone help me figure out what is wrong or any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if PyGame can work with RasPi camera. Do you have problem with camera when you run it with other programs? Do you use camera at the same moment? Only one program can use camera. Did you search this error in Google? Maybe someone already had this problem and resolved it. You could also ask on similar portal for [Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)) and on [forum Raspberry Pi](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/)

Comment: @furas this is a different camera supported by raspberry pi but its not raspberry camera. I tried to google it and the solution does not seem to work as in other cases the problem seems to be way different then mine and the code they are working with is also something else. And only this program is trying to use camera, none other.

Comment: Normally I would use `opencv` to get frame from camera - but it may not work with Raspberry (but `PyGame` also uses `OpenCV` as universal backend - see [PyGame.camera](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html)). Or I would try to use python module [PiCamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/) which was created for Raspberry. And `PiCamera` should use library `libcamera` which I see in your link.

Comment: @furas I tried OpenCV and it has some bugs, the people from OpenCV community addressed the bug and said they would be fixing it but its been 2 months or so and hence I need to find alternative. I am open to suggestion if you have any.

Comment: @furas do you have any idea on using libcamera directly? like maybe and example or something would be great.

Comment: normally you would have to run it as external program using `subprocess.run("libcamera ...", shell=True)` but it seems newer version of Python module [PiCamera2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2) already use `libcamera`. More in PDF with [manual](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/camera/picamera2-manual.pdf)

Comment: @manual I tried Picamera2 its giving issue as well. I don't know what is wrong but Picamera2, Opencv and Pygame and imageio all are giving something or other as error(pygame and imageio had same error and for opencv it's [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/723) and for Picamera2 the error is "Exception: EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import missing"

Comment: I just want a basic libcamera code to access camera, as I am able to get output using libcamera in terminal.

Comment: @manual subprocess.run is working but I want something directly inside python or even c++. I feel I am missing something really small maybe and hence all different libraries are failing.

Comment: directly in Python you have module `PyCamera2`- if you get error with `PyCamera2` then write [issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/issues) on GitHub [PiCamera2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2)

Comment: you can get source code of libcamera in C++ on page [libcamera.org](https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html) and this should allow you to write code in C++. But it may need manually set all options and read source code to see how to use it because I don't see any documentation for this.

Comment: @furas I found a python sample for libcamera [here](https://github.com/kbingham/libcamera/blob/master/src/py/examples/simple-capture.py) but I am not sure how to display those Frame_buffer.

Comment: you will have to use some GUI module - ie. Tkinter, PyQt - or Matplotlib, imageio, opencv. But it may need to get data as `numpy.array` and I don't know what data gives `libcamera`

Comment: @furas libcamera returns framebuffer with lots of weird parameters. I don't know how to display the frame buffer after that

Comment: maybe search in documentation or in source code. using Google `libcamera convert to numpy array` I was in some example (but for PyCamera1) function `request.make_array()`

Comment: @furas I am trying that and I posted a question about the same in Q&A on the github page of libcamera.

Comment: in [helpers.py](https://github.com/kbingham/libcamera/blob/master/src/py/cam/helpers.py#L157) I see it gets `buffer.planes` and it creates numpy array

Comment: BTW: I think text `EGL` in error message may suggest `OpenGL` - and it may need to install some C/C++ library for `OpenGL`

Comment: I found few more helpful functions due to your link, thank you. Will check it out, hope it does the job.

Comment: @furas "EGL in error message", where did you pick that up from?

Comment: in one comment you shows `Picamera2 the error is "Exception: EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import missing" ` and `EGL` in this comment may means `OpenGL Extension`

Comment: @furas oh yes, sorry it slipped through my mind. Thank you

Comment: @furas openGL is installed properly on my device I think, there is some other issue maybe

Comment: @everyone I have some update. I was finally able to view the image using libcamera and the issue was that the code picked up wrong format, the camera is giving YUYV format and the code seems to be assuming it to be NV12 for some reason. I manually set it to YUYV and it worked fine. So do you think this is a camera issue or the code issue?

Comment: I have no idea if it is camera issue, the code issue or rather human mistake. But you could describe it as answer below - and add example code for this. It can be useful for other users.

Comment: @furas, will clean the code and do that (tomorrow, its kinda late here). Thank you once again for your time, I would have taken a lot more time to figure it out without your input.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know what the issue is but I was able to write small piece of code using libcamera(python) to get frames from camera and display them.
You can find the code [here](https://github.com/dhaval-khatri1996/libcamera_python_example)

Note: In my case libcamera was unable to get the correct image format and hence I was unable to convert the frame buffer to an actual image. So I set the format manually, if you wish to do the same then there is a line commented out in the code uncomment it and change the format type to required format type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).